# QBXML Query for Created Date Range

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I'm writing a QuickBooks 2013 integration service.

Synchronization works great, it's filtered by ModifiedDateRangeFilter.
But I need to create "Initial synchronization" which get records from QB by CreatedTime.

Is it possible to create query for Created Date Range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is not possible. See OSR for options available.